# Can I use css offline in blogger instead of external stylesheet

Tags: html, css, xml

I am using blogger for blogging and I want to use CSS in my XML theme. i was using [this stylesheet](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css) in my project, but when I tried to use its content in the style tag, the icons on my blog are not working.
Can anyone guide me on fixing this. I am actually new in coding.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: whenever i tried to use css of this file in <style> tag, it doesn't show me icons

Comment: And what have you tried to debug **why** this happens?

Comment: I can't understand problem. Please tell me if you know what is problem

Comment: How should anybody know what your problem is if you cannot explain it? You haven't provided a single line of code, so nobody can reproduce your problem